# Google street view api parameter altitude always showing "Nan"

Tags: google-streetview-publish

In street view api, while uploading a photo metadata, I am providing the altitude value in meters.

But in the Method: photo.get in the parameter altitude is returning as "Nan".

While sending request.

```
    "pose": {
      "latLngPair": {
        "latitude": 12.9112,
        "longitude": 85.579698
      },
      "altitude": 928.433,
      "heading": 150
    }
```

While receiving request.

```
"pose": {
        "latLngPair": {
          "latitude": 12.9112,
          "longitude": 85.579698
        },
        "altitude": "NaN",
        "heading": 150,
        "pitch": "NaN",
        "roll": "NaN",
        "level": {}
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photo#pose), **`NaN`** indicates an unmeasured quantity. As described in this [link](https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata#metadata_properties), when editing and viewing photo spheres, please be sure to verify and update the metadata accordingly as described later in this document. When specifying the pose and initial heading fields, please be sure to follow the [Euler angle conventions](https://developers.google.com/streetview/spherical-metadata#euler_overview) discussed later in this document.